# Custom HtmlHelper for changing labels

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

i want to provide a method of changing the labels associated with controls which will be rendered on the page via a lookup to a sql table.

Ideally i want to inject the meta data display field which is then rendered on the page using the helper.

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.city)
```

Since this would need to be a  sql lookup at runtime, i cannot just change the class scaffolding tt template to stamp on a displayname annotation at design time.

I thought of 3 potential methods.

1. rewrite all the html.helpers i want to use. Problem with this is you would need to replicate all the functionality of the existing helper prior to making the changes.
2. write a custom data annotation and stamp it on each property in the class i.e.

   [MyCustomNameAttribute] 
   public string city{ get; set; }

   then hopefully in the MyCustomNameAttribute class i can find both the linq field i am referring to, a reference to the metadatamodel and a database context using these i can retrieve and replace the DisplayName based on potential name customisations configured by the User. I tried to do this but was unable to find out how the [Display(Name="city")] annotation works in the background.
3. Modify the entity model backing code to inject the name into the metadatamodel.

Does anyone have any experience of the above?

Cheers
Tim

Comment: Would you be comfortable with one SQL query per label on your page? Probably you need to introduce an in-memory cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a custom `ModelMetaDataProvider` by extending the `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider`.

```
public class CustomModelMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(
        IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes,
        Type containerType,
        Func<object> modelAccessor,
        Type modelType,
        string propertyName)
    {
        var meta = base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);

               if(meta.DisplayName == null)
               {
                 // TO DO read the display value from database and assign here
                 meta.DisplayName = .. 
               }

        return meta;
    }
}
```

Then you have to set that in the Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
   RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
   ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new CustomModelMetadataProvider();
}
```

I'm assuming that you want to set only the display name from db but suppose you want to load the complete modelmetadata from db then I would suggest you to create a custom `ModelMetadataProvider` by implementing the abstract class `ModelMetadataProvider`.

Hitting the database every time definitely not a good idea so we have to workout for some caching strategy.

We have to hit the database for every new `containerType` (I guess) and read the metadata information for the container along with all its properties and store in the cache with key as the `containerType` (this could be a difficult job).

Comment: very useful mark cheers. It would obviously be beneficial to read in the whole of the potential displaynames on first request rather than hitting the database say 20 times for 20 fields. Im not sure if there is an obvious way of achieving this,

Comment: @Tim I agree with you, the solution I provided is bad in that case. I'm asking myself how I forgot that. I'll update the answer.